# How to tweak VSCode support for PowerShell - for better handling the typing of quotation marks

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to have VSCode handle the typing of the quotation marks when editing PowerShell as it handles that in JavaScript? When I type a single `"` I got it suffixed with another. This is OK. however, when the caret is at the end of the string just before the closing `"` - typing another `"`

- will jump past the quote sign in JavaScript (this is the desired as it messes less with muscle memory)
- will insert a new pair of quote sign in PowerShell..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the installation folder of Visual Studio Code and open the
   powershell plugin folder. On Windows it's

   `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.X.X\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.powershell`
2. Open the file `powershellDef.js`
3. Search for `autoClosingPairs`
4. Add the pair for `"` to its value. The code line should look like this now:

   ```
   autoClosingPairs: [['{', '}'], ['[', ']'], ['(', ')'], ['"', '"']],
   ```
5. Restart Visual Studio Code

Now it handles `"` in Powershell files the same way as it does in Javascript files.